# Is it possible to use a Validation Rule to enforce a text field begins with certain characters?

Tags: validation, formula-field

For example, when creating Campaigns, I would like for each Campaign Name field to begin with "FY" - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check it out](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gw8HAAQ).

```
LEFT(Name, 2) = 'FY'
```